# How to confgure django-python3-ldap authentication for Active Directoy?

Tags: python, django, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am currently trying to setup django 1.11 to authenticate with the django-python3-ldap 0.9.14 module.  I found this module here on  https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

I first tested communication with the Active Directory Studio (http://directory.apache.org/studio/) using my credentials.  I noticed that I have to authenticate with the following settings.

Network Parameters
Hostname: serversipaddress
Port: 389
Encryption method: StartTLS extension
Provider: Apache Directory LDAP Client API

Authentication
Bind user: username
password: xxxxx

Then I can connect.

I set the ldap config in the settings.py file, notice that there are specific settings for MS Active Directory.  To test out communication I then ran

```
python3 manage.py ldap_sync_users -v 3
```

I can see that communication worked because it is grabbing the users and inserting them into the django database.

I then promote a user

```
python3 manage.py ldap_promote rmilo
```

But after setting this up, I can't login to the admin page using a rmilo user from ldap. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my configuration?

The error that shows up in the log

```
[25/May/2017 23:17:03] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1813
LDAP connect failed: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - 80090308:
LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for project1 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



# LDAP auth settings.

LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:389"
LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = None
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "DC=ecdc,DC=edgecast,DC=com"

LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "organizationalPerson"

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
"username": "sAMAccountName",
"first_name": "givenName",
"last_name": "sn",
"email": "mail",
}

LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)

LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"

LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = 'username'
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = 'password'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django_python3_ldap": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
    },
}

# Application definition





INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_python3_ldap',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['./templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'project1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',

    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last problem that I ran into was a domain name issue. After adding the line below I was able to login with ldap credentials.

```
LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "ECDC"
```